# Python 3.9: Global variable assuming "impossible" values when backoff and threading are used

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

Here we have an intriguing situation that is not supposed to happens, and seems caused by backoff. Could not find relevant information in the backoff documentation nor related questions.

This code runs in Ubuntu server with Nginx and gunicorn (9 workers enabled) with Python 3.9:

```
# this runs in Ubuntu server with Nginx and gunicorn (9 workers enabled) with Python 3.9


import backoff  # backoff version 2.2.1
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

tries = 0
MAX_RETRIES = 5


@backoff.on_exception(backoff.constant, ValueError, interval=0.5, max_tries=MAX_RETRIES)
def do_stuff_with_backoff_retry(var_1):
    global tries
    tries = tries + 1
    try:
        # do stuff with var_1 that may generate exception and return something if successfully done
        something = var_1
        return something
    except:
        msg = f'Error at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function'
        print(msg)
        raise ValueError(msg)


def controller_func(var_1):
    global tries
    tries = 0
    try:
        result = do_stuff_with_backoff_retry(var_1)
        msg = f'[Try {tries} of {MAX_RETRIES}] success at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function'
        print(msg)
        return result
    except:
        print(f'Failed at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function')




def do_with_threading():
    list_of_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    pool = ThreadPool(15)
    results2 = pool.map(controller_func, list_of_data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(f'results2: {results2}')
```

If the processing is started with `controller_func(5)` (with `var_1 = 5` or any other value) in some rare cases I get the following success message:

`[Try 6 of 5] success at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function`

**It is not supposed to get `Try 6 of 5`, as 5 is the maximum allowed tries.**

In more rare cases I get `Try 7 of 5`.

And if the processing is started with `do_with_threading()` in frequent cases I get messages similar to:

`[Try 11 of 5] success at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function`

`[Try 15 of 5] success at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function`

`[Try 13 of 5] success at do_stuff_with_backoff_retry function`

Looking other logged data seems backoffice is retrying respecting `MAX_RETRIES = 5`, but seems the `tries = 0` at `controller_func(var_1)` is not working properly.

Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you reset `tries` to 0 in each call to `controller_func()`?  Note `tries = tries + 1` is not threadsafe as well.

Comment: @JonSG The `tries = 0` is a tentative to prevent `tries` to assume the value of last run.

Comment: @JonSG I will investigate if is an issue with threadsafe. For me seems related to backoff because happens even if threading is not used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I worked-out to overcome the situation is with Redis.

At controller_func is set the value `0` (zero) to a key into Redis and, then, at the beginning of do_stuff_with_backoff_retry the key is read, converted to integer, the value is increased by `1` and saved again into Redis.

Key name has a variable part associated with the file under processing, that is unique for every thread,, ensuring never will have a key name collision.

E.g:

file_to_process: `dsjfsdo8wejroscmeiuwerl.txt`

`key_name = f'Counter_at_redis_for__{file_to_process}'`